# Themes and Languages Resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml

I was using the standard approach to themes in my WPF application and using a dynamicresource to change it during runtime.

This worked.

Now I have added language support (english, spanish) but when this is set, the dynamic resource no longer works for the theme. If I set the control to a static resource the theme works but then I lose the affect of changing it during runtime.

Heres the code that was added for language support but I'm confused as to why it stopped working the way I want it to.

App.xaml.cs calls this:
    SetLanguage(LocalePath(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name));

```
/// <summary>
    /// Get the locale path for the resource dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="language"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string LocalePath(string language)
    {
        string file = language + ".xaml";

        return Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"Utilities\Resources\Locales\", file);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the language using the defined resource file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file"></param>
    private void SetLanguage(string file)
    {
        if (File.Exists(file))
        {
            var languageDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
            languageDictionary.Source = new Uri(file);

            int dictionaryID = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < Resources.MergedDictionaries.Count; i++)
            {
                var mergedDictionary = Resources.MergedDictionaries[i];

                if (mergedDictionary.Contains("ResourceDictionaryName"))
                {
                    if (mergedDictionary["ResourceDictionaryName"].ToString().StartsWith("Locale-"))
                    {
                        dictionaryID = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (dictionaryID == -1)
            {
                Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(languageDictionary);
            }
            else
            {
                Resources.MergedDictionaries[dictionaryID] = languageDictionary;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... if I add the language resource to the merged dictionary collection after the mainwindow video model is created, would this likely be the cause? 
NVM... tried doing it before no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had 5 other keys in the language resource dictionaries with the same key as the theme being used. Changed the key name and it works again.